# How to transpose a table using unpivot and pivot having varchar columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have this table

```
+----------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
|ATTRIBUTE             |Condition |VALUE         |Person   |
+----------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
|Description of Change |Contains  |description   |XYZ-1    |
|Description of Change |Contains  |datacore      |XYZ-2    |
|Description of Change |Contains  |pulse         |XYZ-2    |
|Item Description      |Contains  |Test Module   |XYZ-3    |
|Item Number           |Equal To  |595-1266-00   |XYZ-4    |
|Item Number           |Equal To  |595-1268-00   |XYZ-5    |
|Item Description      |Contains  |ADR           |XYZ-6    |
+----------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
```

which I want to transpose and show the result in this form:

```
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|Person |Description of Change  |Item Description |Item Number |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|       |Contains               |Contains         |Equal To    |
|XYZ-1  |description            |[NULL]           |[NULL]      |
|XYZ-2  |datacore               |[NULL]           |[NULL]      |
|XYZ-2  |pulse                  |[NULL]           |[NULL]      |
|XYZ-3  |[NULL]                 |Test Module      |[NULL]      |
|XYZ-4  |[NULL]                 |[NULL]           |595-1266-00 |
|XYZ-5  |[NULL]                 |[NULL]           |595-1268-00 |
|XYZ-6  |[NULL]                 |ADR              |[NULL]      |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Here, it can be seen that ATTRIBUTE and Condition will make unique pairs and Person may repeat for more than one entry.

After a lot of research, what I have done is unsatisfactory as shown:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT "ATTRIBUTE", "Condition", VALUE, Person
FROM mytable
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNPIVOT(
    (temp) FOR entry IN ("ATTRIBUTE","Condition", VALUE, Person)
) 
pivot(
    max(temp) FOR entry IN ('ATTRIBUTE' "ATTRIBUTE",'Condition' "Condition", 'VALUE' VALUE, 'Person' Person) 
)
```

which selects only one row.

Maybe I am not using PIVOT and UNPIVOT correctly or there is no solution to this problem. I can write a code in some programming language to get this done but I am compelled to stick with SQL.

Comment: I don't see how you get from your data to your desired output.  What does the first line of data with a `null` value for `Person` represent and where does that data come from?  Where does the `XYZ-2` row with a data value of "pulse" come from?

Comment: What is the difference between `Item Description` and `Item Description` columns?

Comment: Pardon the little mistake in the question which I have fixed now. 

The second table, i.e., the desired output is the table I need in the output, so I wrote on my own. Actually, I want to classify data on the basis of "ATTRIBUTE" and Condition. Therefore, the row where Person is NULL is the containing condition. Person will represent its corresponding data and will be placed in those rows.